# drupal content image not showing

Tags: drupal

I'm doing a drupal site. i want show a facebook image in my page content in home page.

i have edited content of that page.  i have edited the body of that content through admin

and put the text in body like this

The BikeGlow™ Safety Light runs on 2-AA batteries. Light tube length is 10'. Complete unit weighs under 2 oz (without batteries). Light tube attaches to frame with included attachment strips. 
"It's like magic cycling protection from cars!" [< img src='bikeglow_com/sites/default/files/5u84f48n.gif' alt="facebook" />](http://www.facebook.com/bikeglow)

but after saving image is not showing there even that alt tag is not coming.
can any one help me, what will be reason for his

Answer (score 5):

Drupal strips most HTML tags by default when you are creating a Story or Page. Allowed tags in the Filtered HTML mode are `<a> <em> <strong> <cite> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt>` and `<dd>`. As you can see, no `<img>` tag is allowed.

To do this, you can simply open the "Input Format" collapsed box beneath your text area field. If you open this, by default you should have the option to choose between "Filtered HTML" and "Full HTML".

[image: Input Format]

Choose for "Full HTML" and your `<img>` tag should be allowed and the image should show up.

Comment: This will most likely be the cause (+1) - another hint, though: You could also edit the settings for 'Filtered HTML' to allow image tags as well, and you could also create your own, additional, Input Format, configuring it to allow whatever you need. This would give more flexibility if one wants to allow different things for different roles/content types.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a Drupal bug my "Full HTML" input format profile was nor really "full," it was filtering out  identically to "Filtered HTML." Turns out you can configure "Full HTML" and either add more allowed tags, or turn off HTML filtering altogether.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the **image module** and the **image assist module** meet 90% of needs.
For **image module** follow http://drupal.org/project/image
For **image assist module** follow http://drupal.org/project/img_assist

I personally used and it fairly solved my problem.
Hopefully you will like. :)